# VisonOS what are the minimum Hardware Requirements for Simulator

Tags: visionos

I‘d like to get a view on what the minimum hardware requirements to run the visionOS simulator at a realistic frame-rate. Seems to be little information around anywhere that get‘s into that detail.

I‘ve looked around on the developer portal.

Comment: Isn't the requirements the same as Xcode 15 requirements? As for a "realistic frame-rate", this notion is subjective and I doubt there are any official requirement on that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The only hardware requirement that Apple made is the following – **Developing for visionOS requires a [Mac with Apple Silicon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos#)**. Currently, any Mac with M1 processor (no matter how much Unified Memory is installed) is capable of running visionOS Simulator in Xcode 15.